# Proper way to delete has_many :through join records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :posts_tags
end

class PostsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :posts, through: :posts_tags
end
```

When Post gets destroyed I want all of its associations to Tag deleted as well. I do NOT want validations on PostsTag model to run. I just want to deleted.

I've found that adding a dependent on the relationship to posts tags from the Post model works as I want: `has_many :posts_tags, dependent: :delete_all`.

However, the documentation on the subject seems to suggest that I should do this instead: `has_many :tags, through: :posts_tags, dependent: :delete_all`. When I do this, the Tag object gets destroyed and the join object remains.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

> For has_many, destroy will always call the destroy method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run. However delete will either do the deletion according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option, or if no :dependent option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default strategy is :nullify (set the foreign keys to nil), **except for has_many :through, where the default strategy is delete_all (delete the join records, without running their callbacks).**

1. How can I have the default strategy actually used? If I leave :dependent off completely, no records are removed at all. And I cannot just indicate :dependent on a has_many relationship.  Rails comes back and says "The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, :nullify or :restrict ({})".
2. If I don't specify :dependent on either of the relationships, it does NOT nullify the post_id on the PostsTag object as it seems to suggest

Perhaps I am reading this wrong and the approach that I found works is the correct way?

Comment: What happens if a Tag is used by multiple Posts? If one Post is deleted, the other Posts will be affected.

Comment: true, and Tag should have `has_many :posts, through: :posts_tags` not posts, I would use `has_many :posts_tags, dependent: :destroy` to delete posts_tag and leave the tags alone. You can delete orphaned tags with a rake task or console.

Comment: Fixed the association, thanks. I'm just trying to understand the documentation. The wording is confusing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your original idea of:

```
has_many :posts_tags, dependent: :delete_all
```

is exactly what you want.  You do *not* want to declare this on the has-many-though association `:tags`, as that will destroy all associated Tags.  What you want to delete is the association itself - which is what the PostTag join model represents.

So why do the docs say what they do?  You are misunderstanding the scenario that the documentation is describing:

```
Post.find(1).destroy
Post.find(1).tags.delete
```

The first call (your scenario) will simply destroy the Post.  That is, unless you specify a `:dependent` strategy, as I suggest you do.  The second call is what the documentation is describing.  Calling `.tags.delete` will not (by default) actually destroy the tags (since they are joined by has-many-through), but the associated join model that joins these tags.

Comment: Thanks. If for some obscure reason I did want to delete the tags that are associated with the first Post, what syntax should I use?

Comment: @MSC `Tag.where(id: @post.tags).delete_all` is probably the simplest way

Comment: As a clarification point, the first call, `Post.find(1).destroy` is all you need to get rid of the join records.  The second call I guess is an alternate way of doing that?  But it's not needed, assuming the `dependent: :delete_all` is set up and then `destroy` is called.

Comment: @lindes the second call is used when you _don't_ want to destroy the Post, but _do_ want to destroy the h-m-t relations associated with that post

Comment: `Post.find(1).tags.delete(tag)` should be used to remove an association with a specific tag. `Post.find(1).tags.clear` should be used if you want to remove all associated tags.